# dotnet cli test --logger with --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" causes duplicate code coverage files with identical content

Tags: testing, .net-core, coverlet, trx

When running

`dotnet test --blame --configuration Release --no-build --verbosity normal --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --results-directory ./test-results --logger "trx;logfilename=testResults.trx"`

I get muiple code coverage XML files for the same project with the same content in diffrent prefixed folders.

[Project example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CalRQ.png)

How can I get both a code coverage and test report without duplicates.

When removing logger a single coverage report is produces but then I have no test report:

`dotnet test --configuration Release --no-build --verbosity normal --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --results-directory ./test-results"`

When I run with logger, no code coverage is produced.

`dotnet test --configuration Release --no-build --verbosity normal --results-directory ./test-results --logger "trx;logfilename=testResults.trx"`